# jQuery DatePicker Works in All Browsers Other Than Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker that works in all browsers except for firefox. Works in IE, Chrome, but not firefox. Does anyone have any input on why this doesn't work and what a solution may be.

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></


<asp:TextBox ID="firstDate" name="" runat="server" CssClass="fields" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="secondDate" name="" runat="server" CssClass="fields" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

$(function () {
        $("[id$=firstDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        $("[id$=secondDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).bind("change", function () {
            var minValue = $(this).val();
            minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
            minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate() + 1);
            $("[id$=firstDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
        })
    });
```

Comment: What doest $("[id$=firstDate") selector do? Have you tried $("#firstDate") and $("#secondDate") ?

Comment: It does the same, just grabbing the ID from textbox